# vscode debugger variable configuration

Tags: python, variables, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have an example script dividing one number by another number. I try to explore some features of the vscode debugger (I'm somewhat new to debugging) and tried to set variables. I can do this with the debug console (a = 1, b = 2; -> see picture). Doing this for complex scripts, many variables or long file paths seems to be a tedious task.

Is there a way to automate this without using boilerplate code for passing command line arguments to the script?

[image]

Comment: -What kind of automatic operation do you want? There are variables _a_ and _b_ in the code that need to be input by the user. Perhaps input statements are needed here?

Comment: @JillCheng This is just an example for simplicity. Imagine you want to debug some functions of a bigger project that are stored in a separate module (e.g. everything concerning IO). In that case I don't necessary want input statements in each of these modules but I'd like to be able to configure variables (like a and b) which would usually come from other parts of the project. So far I can input these values manually, but I was wondering whether there is a more convenient way to define these variables?

Comment: -Have you tried to use random numbers to generate the values of variables _a_ and _b_?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a launch.json file. VS Code will create this for you.

[image]

Within launch.json add "args". These will be passed into your script when you launch a debug session. You can add multiple debug configurations in launch.json, specify an actual path to your script (instead of just the current file), etc.

Also recommend looking into the python argparse module to help clearly define your arugments (name, data types) and pass them into functions.

launch.json contents:

```py
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["var1","var2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Thx, Jason. I am aware of the args statement in the launch.json. As far as I know it passes the args to the command line, which I could parse with argparse or similar CLIs. The question is whether it's is possible to define variables automatically **without** the boilerplate code for parsing the args from the command line.